# External form action. Post Validate in PHP. Without Javascript

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have this form:

```
    <form name="form2" method="post" action="http://1.1.101.1/reg.php">
        <input id="field12" type="text" value="{$username}" name="username" maxlength="32" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
        <input id="field22" type="text" value="{$password}" name="password" maxlength="32" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        <input name="checkbox" type="hidden" id="checkbox" value="checkbox" />
        <input type="hidden" name="url" value=""/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Connect to WiFi" name="button1" /><br/> 
    </form>
```

the action is a external url.

How can i check in my php when the button submit is posted (name = button1) before it goes to that url.

Right now i have this but its not working becasuse it goes directly to the action url from the form.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "post") {
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: I think you should  try javascript.

Comment: Is it also possible without js ?

Comment: Not possible without JS. When you submit the form, the default action is to submit the form to the URL specified in the `action` attribute. The only way to perform pre-submission validation is to intercept the submission with JS, and perform the necessary validation procedure before moving on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

The only way to validate it without using client side code is to submit the form to your own server side code.

You then won't be able to reliably redirect the request while maintaining POST.

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two options the way I see it.

**If it's not necessary for the user to see the output of the external script**, you could do the posting yourself from your backend. I.e. change the action of your form to your own script and do something like the following:

- Validation the fields
- If validation OK, POST the data to the external URL via CURL (or similar)
- If POST to external URL went OK, redirect to wherever the user should end up in the end

---

**If the user must end up at this external URL**, you could do it in two steps. First have your form action set to your own server side validation. If it passes, give the user a confirmation page with a form containing the same data which would then post it to the external URL. The fields should probably be hidden/read-only on this page to prevent them from being changed before the final submit.

This last method is definitely possible to mess with since it's easy to first use valid values, and then change the data in the HTML before doing the final submit. So if security is important here, you're stuck with the first option.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['button1'])){
 //action
 header('Refresh:3; url=http://1.1.101.1/reg.php');
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: This is not working because the form action is an external url. and the action is called before my own php script.

Comment: Remove the link in form action and try the above script it should work

Comment: Using a refresh header won't work because the POST data will not be POSTed to the URL you are redirecting to.